# How do I make dynamic item slots in Vuetify datatable?

Tags: vue.js, datatable, vuetify.js

I'm learning to code and have a Vuetify datatable where I want to change boolean values in the table to icons. I want to make the table dynamic so I can reuse it as a component, passing props to it depending on page. I can get headers and other stuff to pass as props fine but passing props into the v-slot item in child table is problematic.

I am currently passing a 'booleans' prop from parent which has an array of objects including names of the columns that I want to change to icons and the true/false icons.

Here is the 'boolean' prop array from parent. I've stripped everything else out for readability.

```
 booleans: [
  {
    name: "wo",
    iconTrue: "mdi-account",
    iconFalse: "mdi-office-building",
  },
  {
    name: "ep",
    iconTrue: "mdi-account",
    iconFalse: "mdi-office-building",
  }]
```

The child component is a vuetify datatable.

```
 <template>
  <div>
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="gotData"
      :items-per-page="25"
      :sort-by="sort"
      dense
      :search="search"
      :loading="loading"
      loading-text="Loading... Please wait"
      @click:row="handleClick"
      class="elevation-1"
    >
      <template v-for="(bool, i) in booleans" v-slot:[boolNames[i]]="{ item }">
        <v-icon :key="i" class="mr-3">
          {{ boolNames[i] ? bool.iconTrue : bool.iconFalse }}</v-icon>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </div>
</template>
```

Script

```
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    search: "",
    loading: "true",
    dialog: false,
    gotData: [],
  }),
  props: {
    dataSource: {
      type: String,
    },
    headers: {
      type: Array,
    },
    tableTitle: {
      type: String,
    },
    pageURL: {
      type: String,
    },
    sort: {
      type: String,
    },
    booleans: {
      type: Array,
    },
  },

  created() {
    this.initialize();
  },

  computed: {
    formTitle() {
      return this.editedIndex === -1 ? "New Item" : "Edit Item";
    },
    boolNames: function () {
      return this.booleans.map(function (bool) {
        return "item." + bool.name;
      });
    },
  },

  methods: {
    async initialize() {
      const response = await this.$axios
        .$get(this.dataSource)
        .then((response) => {
          this.gotData = response.data;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
      this.loading = false;
    },

    async addItem(item) {
      this.editedIndex = this.dataSource.indexOf(item);
      this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, item);
      this.dialog = true;
      this.$axios({
        method: "post",
        url: this.dataSource,
        data: this.item,
      })
        .then((response) => {
          this.gotData = response.data;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },

    handleClick(item) {
      this.$router.push(this.pageURL + item.id);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

boolNames[i] returns item.wo and item.ep as I want it to but vuetify sees these as strings not props and so the ternary always reads true and all cells in table are the true icon.

If I hard code item.wo into the template it will work properly, e.g.

```
 <template v-for="(bool, i) in booleans" v-slot:[boolNames[i]]="{ item }">
    <v-icon :key="i" class="mr-3">
      {{ item.wo ? bool.iconTrue : bool.iconFalse }}</v-icon>
  </template>
```

I've tried all sorts of other ways to get this to work but can't figure out.

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, figured it out. I got rid of the computed property and went back to how I started. Just had a syntax error. Here is code that works.

```
      <template
    v-for="(bool, i) in booleans"
    v-slot:[`item.${bool.name}`]="{ item }"
  >
    <v-icon :key="i" class="mr-3">
      {{ item[bool.name] ? bool.iconTrue : bool.iconFalse }}</v-icon
    >
  </template>
```